# Section cell shows separator on device but not in simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5

In my `UITableView` I set the `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` because in each row I want to show a set of pictures and it should like a grid without any separators.

In the simulator it looks like I want it to, but on my iPad (Version 5.0.1) I get a white line at the bottom of the HeaderCell. When I change the `separatorColor` to black the white line changes to black, which proves that it really is the separator. So it looks like my custom section view has a separator while the rows inside the sections do not.

I can "trick" the iPad to not show the separator when I define the header's height to `99` instead of `100` but that clearly is not the way to do it.

Comment: What version of iOS is on the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have the exact answer to your question, perhaps I can point you in the right direction for solving this issue.

I guess you've created custom cells? It sounds to me that it has something to do with the cell frame. In the speedy table view cell code from Tweetie I remember seeing the following code:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame 
{
    [super setFrame:newFrame];

    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds.size.height -= 1; // keep space for de cell seperator
    cellView.frame = bounds;
}
```

Perhaps Apple's default UITableViewCell code act the same when a frame is set and you could override it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I've managed to do as well with IB (last paragraph in my question)

Comment: In that case I *do* think setting the header height (as shown in your question) is actually the correct approach - either that or setting the frame in your custom view in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; ?
```

Comment: This would work and clear for both the simulator and my device, but why is it behaving different on my iPad. What if I actually wanted to set the header's separator, but not the cell's?

Comment: @ Ashely: Give explanation for your answer.